# Rails App Refinery+Devise: Can't access Devise views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, refinerycms

newbie Rails developer here.

I'm trying to create an app that uses Devise for authentication and Refinery for content management. I've followed these tutorials:

http://sdownie.com/blogs/integrating-refinery-rails-3-2-into-your-existing-rails-app
http://refinerycms.com/guides/with-an-existing-rails-31-devise-app

I'm unable to access any of the Devise views on the site. For example when I go to /users/sign_in I get a 404. In my server logs I see the following that makes me think that Refinery is processing the request instead of the Devise routes:

```
Processing by Refinery::PagesController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"path"=>"users/sign_up"}
...
Filter chain halted as :find_page rendered or redirected
Completed 404 Not Found in 39ms (Views: 32.8ms | ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)
```

Any idea how I can correct this and access the Devise sign_in/sign_up views? This is my first stackoverflow question, so if I need to add more specific information let me know.

Much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I mounted refinery at /cms instead of root in my routes.rb:

```
mount Refinery::Core::Engine, :at => '/cms'
```

More info here: 
https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms/issues/2116