# Refinerycms and public folder => Couldn't find Refinery::Page with 'id'=404

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, refinerycms, refinery

I had a project with refinerycms(branch master) and rails 4.1.1.

I'm using carrierwave to upload images and related to a model. The file upload works fine, I saw the images in the public folder:
public/uploads/related_file/file/1/test.jpg

I'm trying to access to that image with the path

```
http://localhost:3000/uploads/related_file/file/1/test.jpg

<%= image_tag related_file.file_url if related_file.file_url.present?%>
```

but I'm getting a 404 error.

Started GET "/uploads/related_file/file/1/test.jpg" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-25 15:43:31 -0500
Processing by Refinery::PagesController#show as JPEG
  Parameters: {"path"=>"uploads/related_file/file/1/test", "locale"=>:en}

Just for testing I'm trying to access the pages 404.html and 505.html at public folder, but this time I'm getting these errors

Couldn't find Refinery::Page with 'id'=404
Couldn't find Refinery::Page with 'id'=500

Apparently refinery is intercepting the requests to public folder.

How I can fix that? 
I just need see the uploaded images in my page, how I can do it??

Edit:

Just for testing I added an image test.jpg to my public folder. when I tried to see that image in the browser I got a 404 error page.

```
http://localhost:3000/test.jpg

Started GET "/test.jpg" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-26 09:57:53 -0500
Processing by Refinery::PagesController#show as JPEG
  Parameters: {"path"=>"test", "locale"=>:en}
```

Please I need help...

Thanks

Comment: I must to add something... those urls work fine a couple of times... but  intermittently... right now I'm getting the 404 error always

Comment: Similar question 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380806/rails-app-refinerydevise-cant-access-devise-views